# Python minidom Trouble obtaining value of child node

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I've read several answers on here regarding this question and am still unable to solve it.

Basically, I want to print the nodeValue of a child node.

Here is the xml:

```
 <issues>
   <maxResultsReached>true</maxResultsReached>
   <paging>
     <pageIndex>2</pageIndex>
     <pageSize>500</pageSize>
     <total>10000</total>
     <fTotal>10,000</fTotal>
     <pages>20</pages>
   </paging>
 <issues>
```

I am trying to get the nodeValue of "total".

Here is what I wrote:

`totalIssues = dom.getElementsByTagName('issues')[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[2]`

I have experimented by so far the only results I got where either `None` or blank space.

Also, how can I get a childNode simply by name? Since many times, there will be another element present which will shift the position of "total" element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it in several steps and be explicit about tag names:

```
issue = dom.getElementsByTagName('issues')[0]
paging = issue.getElementsByTagName('paging')[0]
total = paging.getElementsByTagName('total')[0]
print total.firstChild.nodeValue   # prints 10000
```

Just FYI, you see it is not fun to use `minidom` for xml parsing? Ok, here is an alternative using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library:

```
issues = ET.fromstring(data)
total = issues.find('./paging/total')
print total.text  # prints 10000
```

where `data` is your XML string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked! Also, why would I have to put firstChild? I searched up the documentation on it and still don't really understand.

Comment: @Renren29 great, `firstChild` is needed to get the `Text` node out of the `total` node.

Comment: @Renren29 do you need to help speeding things up? I've seen your post about slow minidom solution.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to speed the code up by a few minutes. I'm pretty satisfied with it and it seems to work reliably.